# Lenovo Ideapad 720S can't resume from suspend on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend

My PC is a Lenovo Ideapad 720S with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed. This PC can't resume from suspend.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `free -h` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Use the `{}` to pretty-fy the text. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Not sure about closing this as there might be a specific reason for the hardware, but the suggested target is nowhere near as good as [How to debug suspend?](//askubuntu.com/q/16239) if anyone wants to add it

Answer (score 0):

You may be resumed but have black screen video failure. System is running, you cannot see. That has been happening to me lately.

Avoid using power button restart. Drive may get corrupted if it is running and you kill with button.

I get another computer and SSH into the one that seems dead. Then trigger restart with

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

This assumes you know IP number of frozen computer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried many things. Although I didn't find the reason of this problem, finally it was solved by change kernel version to  4.19.4 using UKUU.